# AngularJS instantly crashes IE8 on WinXP

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, crash, windows-xp

I'm developing a site using AngularJS v1.2.22 and jQuery v1.11.1.
It is working flawlessly in all browsers, except IE8 (on Win XP).

When the page loads it instantly crashes and i'm left with the following error information:

AppName: iexplorer.exe AppVer: 8.0.6001.18702
ModName: mshtml.dll
ModVer: 8.0.6001.23588
Offset: 001560b5

I've tried on different machines, and the problem persist on all of them.
Has anybody experienced such a problem, and do anyone have a clue what to do?

The site can be accessed here: http://booking.flexybox.com/bowlnfun

Comment: Can you please check which mode the browser is working in when you open the page? (compatibility mode that is)...

Comment: The document mode is set to IE8 standards mode without compatibility mode.

Comment: Did you find a soultion ?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We decided to drop support for IE8 instead.